# Manual Page Break for print is not working in Apache POI excel

Tags: java, excel, printing, apache-poi

I am using XSSFWorkbook, XSSFSheet in Apache POI for excel download. In my excel, there are 154 columns totally. I need to print it in two A3 sheets. 
I have to print first 69 columns in first A3 sheet. Remaining columns in second sheet.

Sheet instance: `XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetNo);`

I had tried

```
    sheet.setAutobreaks(false); 
    sheet.setColumnBreak(68); // index value of 69th column 

    PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
    printSetup.setLandscape(true);
    printSetup.setFitWidth((short)2);
    printSetup.setFitHeight((short)1); 
    printSetup.setPaperSize(PrintSetup.A3_PAPERSIZE);
```

But its not helped. By this, first printout page contains 79 columns(but only 69 need to have)

So i tried by adding

```
sheet.setColumnBreak(153);
sheet.removeColumnBreak(78); // to remove default page break in 79th column
```

It also not worked.

Also i tried as :

```
for(int i=0; i<= 153; i++)
        {
            if(i==68 || i== 153)
            {
                sheet.setColumnBreak(i);
            }
            else
            {
                sheet.removeColumnBreak(i);
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't helped me. Please suggest me to print as i expected. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried accomplishing the same thing in Excel?  I don't think that page breaks work the way you are hoping that they do.

Comment: @Dave Ross  In excel, it is possible to move the page break in Page Break Preview(**View->PageBreakPreview**). and print as i expected. Can we apply this in code?

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.setAutobreaks(false);` doesn't remove auto page breaks.

you should try following code:

```
sheet.setColumnBreak(68);
spreadsheet1.setFitToPage(true);
        XSSFPrintSetup print=spreadsheet1.getPrintSetup();
        print.setFitWidth((short) 1);
        print.setFitHeight((short)0);
        print.setOrientation(PrintOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
        print.setPaperSize(PaperSize.A3_PAPER);
```